# How to get completion to ignore filename extensions

Tags: completion, filenames

It's possible to ask completion to not suggest files with particular file extensions, by:

```lisp
(setq completion-ignored-extensions
      (append completion-ignored-extensions
              (quote
               (".o" ".aux"))))
```

However, I'm not able to determine how to pattern-match on regular expressions *before* the "." and not just after it. For example, I don't want files that end with "_flymake.hs" to be suggested by completion modes. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you happen to try adding `"_flymake.hs"` to the list to see if it worked?  I'm wanting to say that extensions really just means "end of filename"

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin thanks, I tried that. It doesn't seem to work though, at least in a *Helm find files* buffer.

Comment: Are those really regular expressions? Dot character has special meaning in regex, if you want to use literal dot, you need to escape it: `\.`. Also, you want to only match files where these string happen at the end of the string, i.e. `"\\.\\(:?o\\|aux\\)$"`.

Comment: I was using this document as my example: http://www.glue.umd.edu/afs/glue.umd.edu/system/info/olh/Text/Text_Editors/Emacs_text_editor/Customizing_Your_Emacs_Environment/making_changes.txt , starting `(setq completion-ignored-extensions ... )`

Answer (score 1):

The dot is not special in `completion-ignored-extensions`, so

```
(push "_flymake.hs" completion-ignored-extensions)
```

should do the job.  If it doesn't, then I'd guess that it's either because `completion-ignored-extensions` is not used (or used incorrectly) by the completion system you're using, or because all the candidates would be eliminated by `completion-ignored-extensions`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does your completion system/mode even support **regexp** matching? Vanilla Emacs completion does not, out of the box.
2. At any rate, the patterns in `completion-ignored-extensions` are not regexps.  They are not even filename glob patterns.  They are literal text that file names must match at their ends.  In particular, the `.` is not special, but matches a literal `.`.
3. Adding `"_flymake.hs"` to `completion-ignored-extensions` *should* make completion ignore file names that end in that literal suffix.  E.g., file name `"foo_flymake.hs"` should be ignored (not available as a completion candidates). Is this not what you see?
4. Provide a recipe to reproduce your problem, given knowledge of #1-3, above.